# Approximation by polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, approximation

I know the Approximation Theorem of Weierstrass. I think one can apply it to my question but I don't see directly how.

Assume $f$ is a continuous function on the unit interval $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and that $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitary. I want to show that there exists a polynomial of the form $P(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x$ such that $|f(x)-P(x)|<\varepsilon$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. I thought that this is a corollary of thhe approxmiation Theorem, but I think one has to prove that $a_0$ (the absolute term of the polynomial) has to be Zero. Follows this from the fact that $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary Chosen (that we have a unifrom Approximation)?

If we can do that for arbitrary continuous functions we can do this in particular for $\sqrt{x}$ and for $x^2$. But this can be done more specific. I want to Show that for abitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and arbitrary $A>0$ the following holds: There exists a polynomial $Q$ such that $Q(x)=b_1x^4+b_2x^8+\cdots+b_mx^{4m}$ such that $|x^2-Q(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in [-A,A]$. My first thought was that this is true since $x^2$ is the forth power of $\sqrt{x}$. Is this true and how can I make the Argument precise?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Regarding "I thought that this is a corollary of thhe approxmiation Theorem, but I think one has to prove that $a_0$ has to be zero": If you are asked to prove that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is a polynomial $P$, then Weierstrass' theorem is enough. If you have to prove that the is a $P$ that works for each $\varepsilon>0$, it's wrong anyway, unless $f$ is a polynomial on $[0,1]$ (just make $\varepsilon\to0$, then for any $x$, $P(x)-f(x)\to0$, so $P(x)=f(x)$).

Comment: Regarding your second question, notice that $P=Q(x^{1/4})$ is then an arbitrary polynomial. Hence the question is: given a continuous function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x^{1/4})$, is it possible to find a polynomial $P$ such that $|g(x)-P(x)|<\varepsilon$? Weierstrass' theorem answers this question. It won't work as is for negative $x$, but notice your $f$ is even, and so is the polynomial $Q(x)=P(x^4)$.

Comment: Also, the constant term is not really a burden: if $|P(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, then $|P(0)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$ and with $P_0=P-P(0)$, you have $|P_0(x)-f(x)|\leq |P_0(x)-P(x)|+|P(x)-f(x)|<2\varepsilon$. Just halve $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Do I have to edit the question?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I don't understand what you do with $P(x^4)$. Why can one do this?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Why is $Q(x)=P(x^4)$ a good Approximation for $x^2$? Is this directly?

Comment: If $P(x)$ is a good approximation of $f$, then $P(x^4)$ is a good approximation of $f(x^4)$. Just write what a good approximation means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a polynomial $P^*$ such that $|f(x)-P(x)|\le\epsilon/2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Let $P(x)=P^*(x)-P^*(0)$. Then $P(0)=0$ and
$$
|f(x)-P(x)|\le|f(x)-P^*(x)|+|P^*(x)-P(x)|\le\epsilon\quad\forall x\in[0,1].
$$